# VBA Writing Array to Range Causing Run-Time Error '7': Out Of Memory

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array, runtime-error, excel-2010

**The Task**

I'm working on a VBA project wherein I store the data from a sheet in a `Variant Array`, do a bunch of calculations with the data in the `Array`, store the results of those computations in a few other `Arrays`, then finally I store all the "results arrays" in another `Variant Array` and write that array to a range in a new sheet.

Note: this process has been working fine ever since I first wrote the procedure.

**The Issue**

After a very minor logic change, my final `Array` will no longer write to the specified range. I get `Run-time error '7': Out of memory` when I try. I changed the logic back in case that was my issue, but I still get the error.

After doing some research, I tried to erase all the arrays (including the one containing all the sheet data) before writing to the range, but that didn't work either. I've checked Task Manager and that shows my RAM as having a lot of free space (almost 6K MBs available and over 1k Mbs "free"). (Task Manager shows the Excel process as using around 120 MBs.)

**The Code (Snippet)**

```
Dim R As Range  
Dim ALCount As Long  
Dim All(5) As Variant  
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Arr1() As Long
Dim Arr2() As Date
Dim Arr3() As Date
Dim Arr4() As Long
Dim Arr5() As String  

All(1) = Arr1
All(2) = Arr2
All(3) = Arr3
All(4) = Arr4
All(5) = Arr5      

Set R = sht.Cells(2,1)  
R.Resize(ALCount - 1, 5).Value = Application.Transpose(All)
```

**More Details**

```
My device: Win 7 64-Bit  
Excel: 2010 32-Bit  
File Size: <20 MBs  
Macro Location: Personal Workbook  
Personal WB Size: < 3 MBs
```

**Edit: Array Size: 773x5**

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: You might need to show more code. You say the array size is 753x5, but the array is declared as `All(5)` - that's only a 1D array.

Comment: Interesting discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c45d37f1-a5f1-4cf4-938d-69d294d8e447/limitations-on-arrays?forum=isvvba).  They don't come to a conclusion but seem to think that there is a hard limit in some versions of Excel of around 2^16 array elements when writing to a range.  I don't see anything overtly wrong with the code you've included.  When you say "my final `Array` will no longer write to the specified range", do you mean that the code will run fine until that line?

Comment: @TimWilliams I've added the code where I assign the other arrays to `All`. If I'm doing this wrong, how in the world was it able to work before? I haven't changed anything about the arrays since the last time it worked.

Comment: @Blackhawk Yes, every line functions like normal until `R.Resize...` That array size is now `753x5`, but it has been larger in the past (when the code worked), which is another reason this baffles me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

`Arr5` (a string array) was the culprit. Each element in that array is set like so:

```
StrVariable = StrVariable & "--" & StrVariable    
Arr5(ALCount) = StrVariable
```

I forgot to include this line to reset `StrVariable` after each loop:

```
 StrVariable = vbNullString
```

The result meant that by the 773 iteration, Arr5(773) had a massive string length...so massive, in fact, that even though my code could process the array, the sheet could not.

I discovered the error by stopping at iteration 200 and checking the output of `All` into the sheet (at iteration 200 the character count of `Arr5(200)` was already almost 3k).

Thank you for your time and help with this problem!

Comment: @brettdj any idea what's the maximum length allowed in each data type? e.g. [I am aware of the 15 digit case.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-handle-leading-zeros-and-precision-in-number-codes-57f15d52-5c75-4a67-ad35-394ae944d347?CorrelationId=5df97d7f-945d-4736-9637-f52103786f62&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) What about the decimal points a range/cell can hold?